# How to make this Bootstrap Carousel into reusable Razor component to use in Blazor app

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, razor-components

I am building a razor component for use in a Blazor client-side app. I am wondering how i can make the images used in the component dynamic, and set the images in the page code-block where i call the component.

Here is my Carousel.razor component

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@namespace BlazorFrontend.Components

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0"  class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="pictures/foo.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="pictures/bar.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="pictures/foobar.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" id="carouselExampleIndicators-prev" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" id="carouselExampleIndicators-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

@code{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry de in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("ENVVAR: key=" + de.Key + " value=" + de.Value);
                System.Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASSETS"));
            }
        }
        private string AssetsEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASSETS");
        bool firstRender = true;

        protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("initializeCarousel");
                firstRender = false;
            }
        }
}
```

Ideally, i would have liked to do something like this:

```
  <img class="d-block w-100" src=@slide1 alt="First slide">

code{
    string slide1;
}
```

and in the code block of the page i am using the component in:

```
<Carousel></Carousel>

code{
    slide1 = "pictures/foo.jpg"
}
```

for example, but of course, that isn't going to work. What is the right/Blazor way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlazorStrap basically does this already, and their [Carousels sample page](https://blazorstrap.io/carousels) also shows a fairly Blazor-esque way of doing it. From the first example:

```
<BSCarousel NumberOfItems="@items.Count">
    <BSCarouselIndicators NumberOfItems="@items.Count">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @for (int i = 0; i <<> items.Count; i++)
        {
            <BSCarouselItem src="@items[i].Source" alt="@items[i].Alt">
        }
    </div>
    <BSCarouselControl CarouselDirection="CarouselDirection.Previous" NumberOfItems="@items.Count">
    <BSCarouselControl CarouselDirection="CarouselDirection.Next" NumberOfItems="@items.Count">
</BSCarousel>
```

Let's simplify that a little further first:

```
<BSCarousel NumberOfItems="@items.Count">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @for (int i = 0; i <<> items.Count; i++)
        {
            <BSCarouselItem src="@items[i].Source" alt="@items[i].Alt">
        }
    </div>
</BSCarousel>
```

The key aspects to note here:

- there's a Blazor component `BSCarousel` that semantically acts as the container, and can also interact with its child components
- there's *another* Blazor component `BSCarouselItem` for each item added. This approach makes you fairly flexible and might be what you were asking. More tiles in the carousel? Just add another item. The parent `BSCarousel` component, then, needs to deal with arranging them.
- Razor syntax like `@for` and `@items.Count` is used to easily intersperse C# where needed, but really, C# is used here more as a template language
- in contrast, a `@code { }` block isn't needed for this at all (note, though, that everything *outside* that block eventually gets transformed into C# anyway)

I'm guessing your main question was: how do I put multiple items in a component? By making another component that handles a single item. :-)